# How to connect to Snowflake DB with .Net core 3.1?

Tags: .net-core, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've tryied to connect to a snowflake DB following the documentation from the website but this doesn't work (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/dotnet-driver.html)

I already installed the nuget package ***Snowflake.Data*** and here is the code I use to try to connect :

```
using (IDbConnection conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
{
    // Set Connection String
    conn.ConnectionString = "account=xxx11111;user=my_user;password=my_password;host=xxx11111.snowflakecomputing.com";

    // Initiate the connection
    conn.Open();

    IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = " select current_user();"; // Set up query
    IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0)); // Display query result in the console
    }

    conn.Close(); // Close the connection
}
```

The process last longer than a minute then it fails with this :

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnection.Open()
   at POC.Compass.Program.Main(String[] args) in ...\POC.Compass\Program.cs:line 21
```

And line 21 is `conn.Open();`.

Any idea ?

Comment: I even tried to test the code from : https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net

Comment: I added a parameters.json with my params and I get the same error with this code, do I need to enable something from my web interface first or something ?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the warehouse, and possibly the role, from your connection string.

See the documentation for all the parameters: [GitHub](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net#testing-the-connector)

Comment: already tried to add full connection string parameters but with the same result

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your set up. I was able to connect successfully to Snowflake using mostly your code.

Please find an example in [my public Github repo](https://github.com/mzaatar/snowflake-dotnetcore-connector-sample) and compare it with your setup/project.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net Core 3.1, use the Snowflake.Client library. see below code snippet.

```
public SnowflakeClient(string user, string password, string account, string region = null);
```

Configuration file:

```
"SnowflakeSettings": {
    "Account": "AB4444",
    "User": "SOME_SERVICE_ACCOUNT",
    "Password": "Password@123!",
    "Region": "east-us.azure"
}
```

Thanks
Vam